# Patterns in the Collatz conjecture

Tags: pattern-recognition, collatz-conjecture

In regards to the Collatz conjecture, I have been experimenting with a consecutive growing finite set made of odd numbers < 50000

My experiment was to execute the $3n +1$ and then $n/2$ until hitting the first odd number (instead of repeating $3n+1$ till reaching $1$)

from the 50,000, the following starting numbers will hit $1$ as the first odd number: $5, 21, 85, 341, 1365, 5461, 21845$. (growing by $4n+1$)

Then i checked to see what starting points will lead to each of the above points, and you can see how it looks in the following picture:[image]

The first noticed pattern is the repeating growth by $4n+1$

The second noticed pattern is that every 3rd number has no branches (no other starting numbers that lead to it).

What is the meaning of these patterns? and are they expected to continue like this in an infinite set?

Comment: The sequence http://oeis.org/A002450 has a lot of other interesting properties

Comment: Thanks. The patterns also apply to all the other sequences in the “lower branches”

Comment: I suspect that it relates to pascals triangle.

Comment: See the tree in a better graphical display , at http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm the sub-page "numerical and graphical trees" (http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collatzgraphs.htm) . I've assigned a picture like a bottlebrush to the tree, that you've presented. A simpler one (text) is made with excel on the same page. Enjoy... :-)